# Excel: Delete entire row if cell in any column is blank (Long Dataset)

Tags: excel

I am trying to delete all rows that have blank cells in any column in a long dataset (over 60 000 rows in excel)

Comment: Take some extra effort to provide the complete details. Take a look at [how to ask good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Can you just sort by all columns [A-Z] so that blanks are closest to the top? Then you can just eyeball it - select all rows near the top with a blank and delete.

Answer (score 1):

---

### **Step 1:**

Highlight entire dataset and press F5 to make the "GO TO" Menu pop-up. Press the "Special" button.

[image]

---

### **Step 2:**

Select "Blanks" and press OK.

[image]

---

### **Step 3:**

All the blanks should now be highlighted. Press  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  and  <kbd>-</kbd>  to have the "Delete" Menu appear. Select "Entire Row" and press OK.

[image]

Comment: thanx buddy its awesome ....and i need a little help more...i want to select multiple rows if they contain specific text in any cell

Comment: No prob. Please close this question and then create a brand new question.Try to be as specific as possible with your question. Also, explain what steps you have taken trying to solve the problem.